# Unable to get() an 'id' with Cypress "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #Maintenance$Menu"

Tags: cypress

Using an id in a custom Cypress function by keep getting an error that "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #Maintenance$Menu". I can see the id in the inspection tool, and the area is visible. So why do I get this error?

```
Cypress.Commands.add('openMenuItem', (menuString)=>{
    if (menuString.search(">") >= 0){
        var menuNav = menuString.split(">")
        cy.expandMenuItem(menuNav[0])
        cy.get("#"+menuNav[0]+"$Menu").within(()=>{     //this line is where the problem occurs
            cy.contains('span',menuNav[1]).click()
        })


        cy.get('#'+menuNav[1].replace(/\s/g, '')).should('have.text',menuNav[1])
    }

})
```

I expect to be able to select the Id this way but it's not working

[image: Screenshot of Cypress UI with error]

Comment: Try `cy.get('[id="'+menuNav[0]+'$Menu"]')` which is syntactically the same but does not seem to balk at the $ character.

Comment: Thank you, sir. That worked brilliantly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use:

```js
cy.get(`[id="#${menuNav[1]}$Menu"]`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Escaping works with one backslash, like so \.

- ; & , . + * ~ ‘ “ : “ ! ^ # $ % @ [ ] ( ) = > |

--So for this get:
cy.get('a[href^="#/sw/product/create"]').click();

--needed to use
cy.get('a\[href\^\=\"\#\/sw\/product\/create\"\]').click();
Each character has to be prefixed with a \